# How to change Python version to 2.7.8 on Anaconda distribution?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I have some code that requires python 2.7.8. I was using the Anaconda Python distribution, which installed 2.7.6. I'm running Yosemite OSX 10.10.2.

```
vt102:bin steigler$ conda info
Current conda install:

             platform : osx-64
        conda version : 3.4.1
       python version : 2.7.6.final.0
     root environment : /Users/slater/anaconda  (writable)
  default environment : /Users/slater/anaconda
     envs directories : /Users/slater/anaconda/envs
        package cache : /Users/slater/anaconda/pkgs
         channel URLs : http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
                        http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
          config file : None
    is foreign system : False
```

The Anaconda website refers to "*Easily switch between Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4, and experiment with multiple versions of libraries*"

Can anyone explain how to convince Anaconda to use the 2.7.8 interpreter instead of 2.7.6?

Comment: Have you actually *tested* your code with 2.7.6? What specifically about your code requires 2.7.8, and won't work with lower versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the Python version you want to use:

```
conda install python=2.7.8
```

Comment: vt102:bin steigler$ python --version
Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 1.9.2 (x86_64)